# Как подсчитать COUNT с условием в DataProvider?

Tags: yii2

Есть `MyModelSearch`

В методе `public function search($params)`

Пишу `$query = MyTable::find() ->....`, и получаю `dataProvider`.

В `view` в `GridView` передал этот `dataProvider` и вывожу все колонки из таблицы `MyTable`.

К примеру, выводятся 40 записей колонки `temperature`.

Как отдельно от `GridView` на странице вывести значение `Count(temperature > 10)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo MyTable::find()->where(['>', 'temeperature', 10])->count();
```